# How to achieve this curve layout in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

How to achieve this curve layout in Flutter? Any color will do, A huge thanks for your answer.

[image]

Comment: can be outlineBorder path. if stack place the circle negative top. depends where are you trying to do and place on widget tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom clipper to clip the top layout.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
//      backgroundColor: Colors.black.withAlpha(10),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          const ColoredBox(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: SizedBox.expand(),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 300,
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  clipper: MyCustomClipper(),
                  child: const ColoredBox(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Hello World',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 32,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              const Expanded(
                child: SizedBox.expand(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = Path();
    final Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, -size.height * 0.5);
    final Rect rect =
        Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: size.height * 1.5);
    path.addOval(rect);

    final originalPath = Path()
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, 0)
      ..close();

    return Path.combine(PathOperation.intersect, originalPath, path);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: w0w this is perfect. tried it on my emulator and it works like a charm. Thank you @Rahul